# Angular UI-Router breaks Angular Material Flex and md-content

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-material

everybody.

I am using the following:

angular: 1.6.1,
angular-material: 1.1.3,
angular-ui-router: 1.0.0-rc.1

All my views are built using components and I am routing them with the UI-Router 1.x component syntax:

```
$stateProvider

    .state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            component: 'main',
        })
```

For the sake of completeness, my components are laid out as follows:

```
angular
.module('app.main')
.component('main', {
    templateUrl: '/modules/main/main.html',
    controller: MainCtrl,
})

MainCtrl.$inject = [];

function MainCtrl (){

}
```

My index.html is as follows:

```
<body ng-app="app" layout="column" ng-cloak>

<md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <h1>Site Title</h1>
</md-toolbar>

<div layout="column" flex ui-view></div>
```

My view for the main component is irrelevant at this point as the problem starts here. If, for example, my view for main.html is as follows:

```
<div layout="row" flex>
    Content
</div>
```

The div will NOT flex. If, however, it is simply added in place of the ui-view in the parent, it will flex as normal.

```
<body ng-app="app" layout="column" ng-cloak>

<md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <h1>Site Title</h1>
</md-toolbar>

<div layout-align="column" flex>
    Content (THIS WORKS FINE!)
</div>
```

Both contain the same attributes in the inspector apart from the usual differences in using ui-view.

This also seems to be causing problems with md-content, which will only scroll if it is the element in the parent that contains the ui-view. Any nested md-contents will not scroll.

I have also tried using the original ui-router way of routing to controllers and templates which was the norm before the .component syntax.

There is a similar problem listed here: 
[Angular Material layout breaks when using UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982683/angular-material-layout-breaks-when-using-ui-router)

It seems that this gentleman's solution was to abandon UI-Router and use ng-route. I really don't want to move away from UI-Router and am considering completely abandoning Angular-Material but would really prefer to avoid that.

Can anybody please help out with this?